# What does "take over" mean here?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

I ran into a quote by Karl R. Popper:

> “A rationalist is simply someone for whom it is more important to learn than to be proved right; someone who is willing to learn from others - **not by simply taking over another's opinions**, but by gladly allowing others to criticize his ideas and by gladly criticizing the ideas of others”

I am thinking on the phrasal verb *simply take over* here. I know *take over* means *gain control over*, but it does not make an intact sense here? Look like here it mean *only accept*. What does *simply take over* mean here? Could you paraphrase the bolded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an extension of the meaning of ***[take over](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20over)*** which refers to:

> - to assume control or possession of something

The author is saying that a rationalist" will not adopt the opinions of other people" but will gladly allow others to criticize his ideas and  will gladly criticize  the ideas of others.

(M-W)